# Generating a certificate chain in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to generate a chain (self signed + one signed by the self signed) of certificates using Ansible OpenSSL modules.

So far have the following tasks:

```
- name: Generate a Self Signed OpenSSL certificate
  become: yes
  block:
    - apt: 
        name: python-openssl
        update_cache: yes
    - openssl_privatekey:
        path: /tmp/ansible.com.pem
    - openssl_csr:
        path: /tmp/ansible.com.csr
        privatekey_path: /tmp/ansible.com.pem
        common_name: ansible.com
    - openssl_certificate:
        path: /tmp/ansible.com.crt
        privatekey_path: /tmp/ansible.com.pem
        csr_path: /tmp/ansible.com.csr
        provider: selfsigned
    - openssl_privatekey:
        path: /tmp/child.com.pem
    - openssl_csr:
        path: /tmp/child.com.csr
        privatekey_path: /tmp/child.com.pem
        common_name: child.com
    - openssl_certificate:
        path: /tmp/child.com.crt
        privatekey_path: /tmp/ansible.com.pem
        csr_path: /tmp/child.com.csr
        provider: selfsigned
```

But the problem is that child certificate is not valid:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /tmp/ansible.com.crt /tmp/child.com.crt
/tmp/child.com.crt: CN = child.com
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

I am using Ansible 2.6.1

Comment: So what is invalid about those certificates? Both are self-signed and independent of each other. You can't verify one using the other one. It wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I am trying to sign child certificate with the parent (ansible.com) key. Trying to make a chain instead  of two self signed...

Comment: I am signing requests using ansible modules (openssl_certificate): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/openssl_certificate_module.html

Comment: I am not sure how to add code formatting into comments,  there are two blocks responsible for signing certificate requests (the first one is self-signed (e.g. uses own key), and the other one is supposed to be signed by the first). 
    - openssl_certificate:
        path: /tmp/ansible.com.crt
        privatekey_path: /tmp/ansible.com.pem
        csr_path: /tmp/ansible.com.csr
        provider: selfsigned

Comment: I am pretty much sure that self signed certificate is fine, so looks like something wrong with the second block:
```
    - openssl_certificate:
        path: /tmp/child.com.crt
        privatekey_path: /tmp/ansible.com.pem
        csr_path: /tmp/child.com.csr
        provider: selfsigned```

Comment: I still think that the process is different, as I am generating a master_key, master_csr and making self signed certificate afterwords. And separately generating another private key (child), making csr, and now I want to sign it with the master key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176117/discussion-between-oleg-tarasenko-and-techraf).

Answer (score 3):

A self-signed certificate is a self-signed certificate regardless of what key you provided for signing (this key is never verified anyway, because "you trust the certificate directly").

If you check the contents of the `child.com.crt` certificate with `openssl x509 -in /tmp/child.com.crt -text -noout` command, you'll see:

```
Certificate:
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=child.com
        Subject: CN=child.com
```

not `Issuer: CN=ansible.com` (and there is no way to know whose key it is during the signing task, based on the key alone ― a key is just a random number; you'd need to provide the certificate of the signing party somewhere in the task, which you don't).

---

What you want to achieve will be possible in Ansible 2.7 with a new provider `ownca` introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/b61b113fb9e3fcfcb25f4a8aaabad618e3209ce1):

> The 'ownca' provider is intended for generate OpenSSL certificate signed with your own CA (Certificate Authority) certificate (self-signed certificate).
>
> [ ]
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> - name: Generate an OpenSSL certificate signed with your own CA certificate
>   openssl_certificate:
>     path: /etc/ssl/crt/ansible.com.crt
>     csr_path: /etc/ssl/csr/ansible.com.csr
>     ownca_path: /etc/ssl/crt/ansible_CA.crt
>     ownca_privatekey_path: /etc/ssl/private/ansible_CA.pem
>     provider: ownca
> ```

For now (up to Ansible 2.6.x) you need to call `openssl x509 -req` (see [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/2947502)) with the `command` module.

Comment: _A self-signed certificate is a self-signed certificate regardless of what key you provided for signing (this key is never verified anyway, because "you trust the certificate directly")._
This is not true. Nowadays many appliances require that final certificate enjoys participating in a full chain and both intermediate and root certificates have proper purpose and capabilities specified.